# Is there any way in flask to execute this SQL statement

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I've spent all day trying to figure out how to convert this SQL code into flask sqlalchemy code/anything that will run in the flask application.

```
#    SELECT COUNT (DISTINCT date) FROM quizVenue
#    WHERE name='Crows'
```

I'm expecting the returned value to simply say something like '{{ name }} has played {{ quizzesPlayed }} quizzes' on the list.html page I'm trying to populate.

This is the existing code I have that fills a table for all entries of a chosen player name (apologies if the variables are a bit confusing)

```
@app.route('/quizVenue/<name>')
def quizVenue(name):
    quizVenue = Quiz.query.filter_by(name=name).all()
    quizzesPlayed = Quiz.query.SOMETHING HERE.

    return render_template('list.html', quizVenue=quizVenue, name=name, quizzesPlayed=quizzesPlayed)
```

I've tried all variations of this to try and pull it together but I'm still exactly where I started.

```
quizzesPlayed = db.session.query(func.count(distinct(Quiz.date)))
```

Or

```
db.session.query(func('SELECT COUNT (DISTINCT Quiz.date) FROM payneham_tavern WHERE name="Crows"'))
```

My model view:

```
class Quiz(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'quizVenue'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    date = db.Column(db.String)
    round = db.Column(db.Integer)
    question = db.Column(db.String)
    name = db.Column(db.String)
    question_points = db.Column(db.Integer)
    total_points = db.Column(db.Integer)
```

I'd really appreciate any sort of fix to get this working. Thank you.

Comment: Why do you need distinct  dates?  Is it possible that there can be more than one "name" and a given date?

Comment: I'd like each page to show how many times that a team has played a quiz. A quiz can have x number of teams, and the way the database is laid out shows an entry for each question, per team. So a team may appear around 50 times for any given date if they were playing at that time.

Comment: Something like `Quiz.query(db.distinct(Quiz.date))...` should work (if it doesn't like `db.distinct` you can `import distinct from sqlalchemy`).  But I'd consider reviewing your database design; you probably want a [many to many](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/basic_relationships.html#many-to-many) relationship between quizzes and teams, maybe also between quizzes and questions and teams and questions.

Comment: Quiz.query(db.distinct(Quiz.date) would just search for all unique dates from the entire database, I need it to search for all unique dates that a name has participated in. The database has been written directly from a log file that the quiz outputs. It's a bit of a hacky method but as a beginner I just wanted to get something working, even if it wasn't completely efficient. Proving very frustrating!

Comment: The `...` was meant to imply to add whatever filters you want after that

Comment: Oh I see, with the distinct import from sqlalchemy it returns with 'TypeError: 'BaseQuery' object is not callable'
I've tried different variations like:
```
quizzesPlayed = Quiz.query(db.distinct(Quiz.date)).filter_by(name=name).count()
quizzesPlayed = Quiz.query(db.distinct(Quiz.date)).filter_by(name=name)
quizzesPlayed = Quiz.query(db.distinct(Quiz.date))
```

Comment: Try `Quiz.query(db.func.count(Quiz.date.distinct())).filter(....)` or perhaps `db.session.query(db.func.count(Quiz.date.distinct())).filter(...)` - not quite sure how Flask-SQLA constructs these queries.